# Add multiple Strings to a ListArray?

Tags: android, arrays, string, arraylist

I have about 70 strings that I would like to add to a String Array.. Then print the String array in a TextView..

I have did some homework and I think I actually want to add the strings to a ListArray.

The Strings are located in the string.xml file.

```
TextView tvHerb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHerb);

    ArrayList<String> herbList = new ArrayList<String>();
    herbList.add(R.string.angelica, null);
    herbList.add(R.string.anise_seed, null);

    tvHerb.setText(herbList.toString());
```

I get a runtime error as soon as the layout is displayed on emulator.

I am LOST!!! I am also new to android programming so any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `context.getString(id)` to get the string resources.

Also is there some reason you're using the 2 argument version of `.add`?

You probably want `herbList.add( context.getString( R.string.angelica ) );`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having each string with id in string.xml file. you can declare a string array in string.xml

```
   `<resources>
   <string-array name="sample">
   <item>YourValue1</item>
   <item>YourValue2</item>
    .....
   <item>YourValue70</item>
   </string-array>
   </resources>`
```

Then in your activity

```
   `String[] sample = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sample);
   ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(sample.length);
   arrayList = Arrays.asList(sample);`
```

Comment: I would like seperate strings so I can call the string elsewhere in the app.. instead of having to know the position of the <item> I can call herb1$ herb2$ (excuse the syntax)

Answer (score 0):

First I agree with agreco's answer about the number of attributes.

But also, if you are adding in your arraylist only Strings which come from you string ressource, I think it would be better to define a array of String directly in your strings.xml file.

However, I guess your problem comes from the fact that you apply toString to an ArrayList. toString is a generic method, and I'm not sure of its behavior with an array. toString does not necessarily fits your exact needs, and most of the time it does not.

I think you should better do something like :

```
String stringToInsert =herbList.get(0);

    for (int i=1;i<herbList.size();i++)
    {
        stringToInsert+="ANY_SEPARATOR_YOU_WANT" + herbList.get(i);
    }

    tvHerb.setText(stringToInsert);
```

Comment: the separator, i didnt think it could be a new line.. so i changed it from a TextView to a ListView.. I am working on how to get text to listView   ListView.setText doesnt exist...

Comment: A ListView and a TextView are completely different (take the time to read this before using a ListView : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)
Concerning the separator, you can use "\n" to go to a new line.